# Альтернатива полигональному рисованию объектов в OpenGL

Tags: opengl

Проблема вероятно знакома всем. Для рисования  плавных, не остроугольных объектов требуется огромное количество полигонов. Иногда оно превышает все мыслимые пределы. В качестве варианта можно использовать тесселяцию, но и она, как мне кажется не самый оптимальный способ. Какими могут быть решения? Например, требуется нарисовать слегка закругленную стену и натянуть на неё текстуру. Многие примитивные объекты можно задать с помощью математических уравнений, но как в итоге получить конечный продукт на экране – это и есть суть вопроса.  Сложные модели людей, транспорта и архитектуры уравнением изобразить почти невозможно, но всякие торы, сферы, трубы, кубы с закругленными углами и всевозможные модификации, вполне можно представить подобным образом.

Answer (score 2):

> Для рисования плавных, не остроугольных объектов требуется огромное количество полигонов. Иногда оно превышает все мыслимые пределы.

Когда ты доделаешь игру, выйдут новые видеокарты, и эти пределы отодвинутся. Да и сейчас видеокарты глотают миллионы полигонов и не давятся. Сейчас для игр нет никаких альтернатив полигональной графики.

> Например, требуется нарисовать слегка закругленную стену и натянуть на неё текстуру.

Шейдеры с правильно расставленными нормалями могут помочь сгладить это, и из 10-гранной призмы сделать неплохой цилиндр.

Трассировка лучей лучше всего рисует фигуры, задаваемые уравнениями, но пока она медленная. Надо подождать лет 5. Хотя, пока делаешь игру, они уже пройдут.

> Сложные модели людей, транспорта и архитектуры уравнением изобразить почти невозможно

Людей вряд ли возможно, а вот транспорт и здания состоят из деталей более-менее правильной формы. Можно задать их несколькими уравнениями.
 Посмотри вот эту тему:

[Фрактальный игровой мир](http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=146616)

Тут есть много картинок, некоторые из них вполне нормальные, сделаны при помощи трассировки лучей. Как тут пишут, у них работает это почти в реальном времени.

Comment: Тема весьма интересная. И скриншоты неплохие. Чем дальше - тем лучше. Сложность сцены возрастает. Но для начала неплохо бы потренироваться на чем-то простом, а не залезать в дебри сложных фрактальных объектов.

Comment: Он пишет, что у него всего одна формула создаёт эти "дебри сложных фрактальных объектов". Там всё происходит в одном небольшом пиксельном шейдере.

Answer (score 0):

Я только слышал про способ где объекты рисуются пиксельно, где пиксель представлен в виде объемного шара например. При очень близком рассмотрении объекта можно видеть решетку из этих шаров, а издалека как единое целое выглядит.

Comment: Воксельные движки.